# Will gtk2hs and wx ever build more reliably?

Tags: haskell, gtk, installation, gtk2hs

This is not a rant; it's a technical question.

Haskell coders of all abilities seem to agree that building gtk is a huge hurdle. Even experts seem to cross their fingers when they cabal-install it. It's a large system with many components; the age and version of the components varies wildly on the systems gtk is being installed on; some pieces and configurations are completely different on different OSes, etc.

Are these technical limitations that will be with us forever? Or are there other causes of build-unreliability, that can be worked out in the future?

Comment: I believe this is an OS issue regarding library accessibility and usage; I have never heard of any "expert" having problems on Linux, etc.

Comment: Maybe some "real" experts can back me up here, but in person I've talked to several who agree it often won't build on the first try, and takes a lot of tinkering

Comment: OS X and Windows may be worse than Linux, but this is my exact question: how much of the variation in users' systems will cause this to never work, vs. how much is just current limitations of code and/or build systems?

Comment: My understanding is this: the exact same problem occurs with someone wanting to use Python bindings to GTK+ or wxwidgets on Windows or OSX.  I have *never* had a problem building either on *nix (though I also know that I need to install the actual C libraries and headers).  e.g. building pygtk on Win32 looks similar to building gtk2hs on Win32: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq21.001.htp vs http://aadamov.wordpress.com/2010/12/11/gtk2hs-installation-under-windows-and-haskellgui-programming-with-gtk2hs/

Answer (score 2):

I think a major issue is that gtk2hs relies on resources outside of the scope of Cabal--it needs external libraries to work properly. Cabal is great for Haskell-only stuff, but it is not particularly good at supporting external resources and dependencies.

I think the best hope for a stable gtk2hs build would be using the system's package manager, largely because these package managers are much better at handling all these different dependencies.

However, take everything I've said with a grain of salt: I have little first-hand experience; I'm basing my thoughts mainly off stuff I've read like [this post](http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/).

Comment: I will not agree with you that cabal is great. In fact it is not as feature rich(it lacks most basic uninstall functionality) as decent package managers.

Comment: @Trismegistos: That's because it's more of a build system than a package manager. So it's useful for building, testing and even does some basic dependency resolution, but that is all. That's what the article I linked to is all about :P The summary is that you should use your OS's package management for nontrivial stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk2Hs actually made a good effort to become much easier to install, it is currently very easy to do so on Windows : You install the "all-in-one-package" from GTK, then "cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools" then "cabal install gtk" and it works... On linux it's not much harder : you just need to install the development packages for gtk before the cabal sequence.

I would not say this is perfect and works each and every time (some versions of GTK have to be avoided, though not the most recent), but the situation is now much better than it was in the past (before cabalization).

Of course the main problem is not really with Haskell in all those cases, it is with the C part of the library, Haskell and Cabal bring their own woes to the table but they're not really related and I continue to hope that some improvements to cabal-install and especially ghc-pkg will help in the future (excellent article to read on the potential problems : http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml , every one should be forced to read it before wielding cabal !).